# Realtime Web to Mobile Chat Application Using Firebase

Tags: android, angularjs, mobile, push-notification, firebase

We are building a real-time mobile to web text & image chat application using [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/). Consumers can send  messages to 10 categories for example, TV Help, Computer Help, Camera Help etc from an android mobile app.  Agents will receive messages on an AngularJS web app where they can reply. Now, one category can have many agents under it.

For example, if ConsumerA sends a message to "Camera Help", the messages should be routed to AgentA & AgentB, if they are handling "Camera Help". Any of them can reply to the consumer.

What is the best way to structure a firebase database for this use case?

Also, we would like to send consumers android push notifications if the app is not in use. I have heard you can use a [firebase queue](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-15-introducing-firebase-queue.html), but it seems challenging, are there any examples of this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific question here that can be answered in a few paragraphs? The gist of this question is "how do I write my app." The best way to structure a firebase database is [covered in the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html), and specific to your use case. You'll note it's several pages long. Push notifications have already been answered here on stack overflow and on the mailing list. Examples are listed on the Firebase site.

Answer (score 1):

Well if I am to design your firebase it would be like,

Customer_name

Customer_number

Customer_address...and other customer related data

Category_of_item

Message

Time and date of message

The part of using firebase for push notifications is concerned, then there is no direct support for that in firebase I would suggest you to go for parse or GCM. Cheers :)